# Fitting Rayleigh in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

This code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
# Generate gamma rvs
x <- rgamma(100000, shape = 2, rate = 0.2)
den <- density(x)
dat <- data.frame(x = den$x, y = den$y)

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme_classic()


# Fit parameters (to avoid errors, set lower bounds to zero)

fit.params <- fitdistr(estimate, "gamma", lower = c(0, 0))

# Plot using density points

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +     
  geom_line(aes(x=dat$x, y=dgamma(dat$x,fit.params$estimate["shape"], fit.params$estimate["rate"])), 
color="red", size = 1) + 
  theme_classic()
```

fits and plots the distribution of series `x`. The resulting plot is:
[image]
Packages `stats` and `MASS` seem not to support the Rayleigh distribution. How can I extend the previous code to the Rayleigh distribution?

Comment: You do not define `estimate`, if I use `x`, returned by the call to `rgamma`, the fit is perfect. The [Rayleigh distribution](http://search.r-project.org/library/VGAM/html/rayleighUC.html) is implemented in package `VGAM`.

Comment: can you clarify? Your example shows a fit to Gamma, you want to do the equivalent for the Rayleigh distribution? Check the `fitdistrplus` function and the Distributions task view (did you do a web search before asking? did you find anything? googling "fit Rayleigh R" comes up with useful links for me ...)

Comment: @BenBolker, Yes I'm looking for the equivalent for the Rayleigh distribution. I did search before asking this question but couldn't find anything well explained that would help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below I start by recreating the vector `x`, this time setting the RNG seed, in order to make the results reproducible. Then a data.frame `dat` with only that vector is also recreated.

The density functions of the Gamma and Rayleigh distributions are fit to the histogram of `x` by first estimating their parameters and with `stat_function`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(extraDistr)  # for the Rayleigh distribution functions

# Generate gamma rvs
set.seed(2020)
x <- rgamma(100000, shape = 2, rate = 0.2)
dat <- data.frame(x)

# Fit parameters (to avoid errors, set lower bounds to zero)
fit.params <- fitdistr(dat$x, "gamma", lower = c(0, 0))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = nclass.Sturges(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dgamma,
                args = list(shape = fit.params$estimate["shape"], 
                            rate = fit.params$estimate["rate"]), 
                color = "red", size = 1) + 
  ggtitle("Gamma density") +
  theme_classic()


fit.params.2 <- fitdistrplus::fitdist(dat$x, "rayleigh", start = list(sigma = 1))
fit.params.2$estimate

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = nclass.Sturges(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = drayleigh,
                args = list(sigma = fit.params.2$estimate), 
                color = "blue", size = 1) + 
  ggtitle("Rayleigh density") +
  theme_classic()
```

---

To plot points and lines like in the question, not histograms, use the code below.

```
den <- density(x)
orig <- data.frame(x = den$x, y = den$y)

ggplot(data = orig, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y), size = 3) +     
  geom_line(aes(y = dgamma(x, fit.params$estimate["shape"], fit.params$estimate["rate"])), 
            color="red", size = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = drayleigh(x, fit.params.2$estimate)), 
            color="blue", size = 1) + 
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thank you @Rui Barradas. I see that the result is formed by an histogram and the resulting fitting curve. I would like to know how you can draw a figure like mine (red curve and black curve) instead of the histogram.

Comment: thank you! I accepted your answer. I only have one last question. How can I export the values drawn from the code yoo wrote in the edit? (To plot points and lines like in the question...)

Comment: @Mark If you want the `dgamma` and `drayleigh` values, call the functions exactly like in the plot code but assign the return values to, say, `ygamma` and `yrayleigh`.